# How do I expose a civicrm profile to collect data from anonymous user (an application form) on a drupal node?

Tags: civimember, profile, webform-civicrm

I have created a civicrm profile with the basic data I need. I have set all the fields to "public and listing," made them searchable. I have also set the form to add users to a group and to limit users to another group in listings. But now I am looking for the html code snippet so I can place the profile on a node in D7. I don't see anything but "Preview, Profile Create Mode, Profile Listings Mode,disable, Delete and Copy Profile" in the "more" link. Where is the html? I want this to be exposed to anonymous users so they can fill out and submit as an application form.

Answer (score 2):

On Drupal -> how about simply use the URL - e.g.

```
civicrm/profile/create?reset=1&gid=30
```

and then add blocks with visibility settings show on civicrm/profile/create etc to dress up the page?

I would not recommend HTML code snippets - I do highly recommend webform_civicrm! :-)

Comment: Excellent idea! Why didn't I think of that! I keep forgetting that a civi page ain't nothin but a drupal node anyway. I love workarounds like that! Yes, I'll just expose some blocks on the profile pages. And I agree with both of you, Peter and Karin, webform_civicrm is right tool for this job, and it really isn't complicated. Just thought I'd do it with profiles and add a bunch of snippets. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to place it on a node. The link to Profile Create Mode would allow anonymous to create a contact record. If that is what you mean.

Being on Drupal, you can also consider using webform_civicrm rather than civicrm Profiles

Comment: I'd like to put some other content around the form (and maybe some other "profile" forms) on the same page. The documentation suggests that there is something called a "code snippet" for profiles. Maybe I misunderstood. Not possible? I don't like using Webforms for this. Too complicated (blasphemy!). The profiles are done, just want to insert them into a node.

Comment: ha blaspheme all you like :-) Ys there used to be 'html snippet'. Odd. Maybe relates to "civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1" and "Accept profile submissions from external sites" - certainly suggests this is outdated https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Linking+Profiles#LinkingProfiles-ContactCreationorSign-upFormsusingProfileHTMLFormSnippet

Comment: certainly harder than it used to be